Is there an interpretation of the pointwise maximum of CDF's?
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables, with CDF's given by $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(x)$, respectively.  Is there a known interpretation/significance of the pointwise maximum of $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(x)$?
There is the well-known fact that the CDF of $\max(X,Y)$ is given by the product $F_X(x) F_Y(x)$, but I am curious about the opposite direction: is there anything we can say about the random variable whose CDF is $\max(F_X, F_Y)$?  Even in very simple cases?

It is a valid CDF, meaning there exists a random variable $Z$ with CDF $\max[F_X,F_Y]$. The random variable $Z$ is said to be "stochastically less than or equal to $X$," so that (by extending the space to include an independent $U[0,1]$ variable) $Z\leq \tilde{X}$ surely, for some random variable $\tilde{X}$ that is distributed the same as $X$. $Z$ is also stochastically less than or equal to $Y$. If $X, Y$ are identically distributed then the distribution of $Z$ is the same as that of $X$.

I encountered a situation like this in the context of tabletop roleplaying games. Consider the following type of game mechanic:

We roll a bunch of dice. (The dice do not necessarily have identical distributions.)
After seeing the initial rolls, we get one chance to choose none, some, or all of the dice to be rerolled (simultaneously).
After the reroll, the numbers shown will be fed to some scoring function (e.g. sum, largest matching set, longest straight). We want to maximize the probability of the score being greater or equal to some known threshold. However, we may encounter different thresholds as we run this mechanic repeatedly throughout the course of the game, e.g. in one individual contest a pair may be good enough, but another might require a triple.

For $n$ dice, once we reach step 2, there are up to $2^n$ possible choices of which dice to reroll. Each such choice produces a distribution of scores. Since we know the threshold ahead of time, for any threshold we can pick the choice that maximizes the probability of success. If we tabulate this for all possible threshold values, we have the pointwise maximum of the individual survival functions, which itself has the structure of a survival function as noted by Michael's comment under the question.
Unfortunately it's not straightforward to interpret the "events" of the resulting implied PMF, since it was not really generated by a single decision process. We could try taking a page from inverse transform sampling and imagine that we first draw a "luck" value uniformly between 0 and 1, then ask what is the highest threshold we could hit with that amount of "luck", though I find this not totally satisfying.
